# Uanble to move turtlebot 3 using teleop

Tags: python, ros, gazebo-simu, rqt

I am unable to move my turtlebot3 using teleop and keyboard.
I am able to change the linear and angular velocity but the bot is not moving. [image]

This is what my rqt graph looks like. I think the reason is that gazebo gui is not subscribed  to cmd_vel. How do i make gazebo_gui subscribe to cmd_vel ?

Comment: You need to post more information if you want any help. i.e. what does your launch file look like?

Comment: I am using ros noetic 1.16.0 with turtlebot3 and gazebo

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by running this

```
sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-pkgs ros-noetic-gazebo-ros-control
```

This makes gazebo subscribe to cmd_vel.
Rqt graph now looks like this
[image]